# Fill variable from query in Oracle Package

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want populate variable from query in oracle package.

In package I'm define:

```
   g_my_value number;
   g_my_value2 number;
   
   PROCEDURE initialize_par;
```

In package body:

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY my_pkg AS 
    PROCEDURE initialize_par AS
    BEGIN
      Select parameter_value into g_my_value from tbl_parameters where name = 'my_value'; 
      Select parameter_value into g_my_value2 from tbl_parameters where name = 'my_value2'; 
    END initialize_par;
```

Before use variable in other procedure in this package I need call
Exec initialize_par to set value in variable.

Is it good option? Is it possible set value in variable without procedure initialize_par?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [initialise a package](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/packages.htm#LNPLS99926) (without a procedure) using a `BEGIN`/`END` initialiser block in the procedure body:

```sql
CREATE PACKAGE package_name IS
  g_my_value number;
  g_my_value2 number;
END;
/

CREATE PACKAGE BODY package_name
IS
BEGIN
  Select parameter_value
  into   g_my_value
  from   tbl_parameters
  where  name = 'my_value'; 

  Select parameter_value
  into   g_my_value2
  from   tbl_parameters
  where  name = 'my_value2'; 
END;
/
```

Given the sample parameters:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl_parameters (name, parameter_value ) AS
  SELECT 'my_value',  42     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'my_value2',  3.141 FROM DUAL;
```

then:

```sql
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(package_name.g_my_value);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(package_name.g_my_value2);
END;
/
```

Outputs:

```
42
3.141
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6JklGQEz)

Comment: @user_odoo Please [read the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_package_body.htm#GUID-68526FF2-96A1-4F14-A10B-4DD3E1CD80BE__BABFJIFI) on the correct syntax as the declarations come first and the initialiser comes last.